# loader:936 throw err; / Windows

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger

**Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'morgan*'*

Hi.
Can somebody help me please I don't know how to fix this?

Any of the mentioned solutions in previous posts did not work...

Thanks

Comment: it looks like morgan is not imported successfully. possibly you didn't install morgan, you need to run 'npm install morgan --save' Can you attach your code here?

Comment: Hi. I managed to find another alternative to my problem. Basically, I wanted a debugging tool for JavaScript as I just started to learn JS and I need a lot of support to implement my logic into computer logic. Hope it will come with practice. I appreciate so much your support and sorry for the late reply. Many thanks!